# SQL | Inner query will return multiple rows against which outer query should run multiple time for each row from inner query

Tags: sql, oracle

Inner query `select unique(upper(agent_name)) from admin.agent` will return multiple agent present in environment.

```
select count(*), agent from admin.connection where agent like upper((select unique(upper(agent_name)) from admin.agent))  AND is_active=1 AND is_currver=1 group by agent;
```

Against to each agent wanted to know how many connections are present in environment which can be check from `select count(*), agent from admin.connection where agent like 'agent1'  AND is_active=1 AND is_currver=1 group by agent;`

I am getting error as below..

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Desired result will be something like below.

```
17 agent1
0 agent2
22 agent3
89 agent4
```

Comment: change your subquery like this - select DISTINCT upper(agent_name) from admin.agent

Comment: Why `like` instead of `in`? Are agents wildcarded?

Answer (score 0):

With `group by` you need no `distinct` nor `unique`.

```
select count(*) cnt, upper(a.agent_name) agent 
from admin.agent a
left join admin.connection c on upper(a.agent_name) = c.agent
and  c.is_active=1 and c.is_currver=1 
group by upper(a.agent_name);
```

Comment: Above query is giving the counts for agents against which some connection is there but not listing the agents against which no connection is there..